# How to call actionmethod of a controller from a JavaScript function or a MVC Core razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

MVC Core razor view page. Two selectLists. One for company and another for clients of that company. When we select the company from its dropdown list, we want to refresh clients list in its dropdown list.

1. Which script language should we use here to catch the onChange event of selectList?
2. How can we invoke actionmethod of a controller from the viewpage or within a JavaScript function.

I tried several tutorial but none of them worked.

For example controller=Company and ActionMethod=Index and we want to pass an int.

Thank u dear in advance!

I wrote this code but this does not fire up when I change the selectlist value.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CompanyId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="CompanyId" id="CompanyId" class="form-control" asp-items="@( new SelectList(ViewBag.CompanyList, "Id", "CompanyName"))"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CompanyId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>


    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientId, new SelectList(" "), "--Select Client--", new { @class = "form-control" })




        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CompanyId").change(function () {
        $.get("/RentalObject/GetClientList", { CompanyId: $("#CompanyId").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#ClientId").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#ClientId").append("<option value='" + row.ClientId + "'>" + row.ClientId + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
        </script>
```

**And in the actionMethods**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        List<Company> CompanyList = _context.Company.ToList();
        ViewBag.CompanyList = CompanyList;
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetClientList(int CompanyId)
    {
        //_context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Clients> ClientList = _context.Clients.ToList();
        return Json(ClientList);

    }
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad  what you need is a cascading dropdown list, so kindly follow the two links below, it was very useful and you surely get the way:http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b58fde6b-415e-454d-985b-d5dc4ad2fca8.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc/

Comment: Thank you Karthik. It really helped me in solving the problel.

Comment: my pleasure and am glad that it helped .Happing sharing